# Performance issue while Update remote database from local database

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

1. I tried to update remote table(dblink) from local database through trigger.
   I costs around 24990. Table data count nearly 3032965.

```
UPDATE remote_table
SET ip_stats = (
  CASE 
    WHEN :NEW.ip_stats IN (22,30,)  THEN 'Non-Network'
    WHEN :NEW.ip_stats IN (23,31,182)  THEN 'Cancel'
    WHEN :NEW.ip_stats IN (24,32)  THEN 'file'
    WHEN :NEW.ip_stats IN (26,34)  THEN 'online'
    WHEN :NEW.ip_stats IN (63)  THEN 'decrease'
    WHEN :NEW.ip_stats IN (64)  THEN 'increase' 
    END) ,
  ip_comments = (
  CASE :NEW.ip_commts
    WHEN 154 THEN 'increase'
    WHEN 155 THEN 'previous'
    WHEN 156 THEN 'hardware'
    WHEN 157 THEN 'software'
  END) ,
  feedback           = :NEW.feedback ,
  changed_by         = :NEW.changed_by ,
  create_dt          = :NEW.create_dt ,
  status             = 'Y' ,
  sum_amount         = NVL (:NEW.net_amount ,0)
WHERE     ID     = :NEW.new_key;
```

Below is the explain plan for update statement.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Inst   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT REMOTE|                 |     1 |   195 | 24990   (2)| 00:05:00 |        |
|   1 |  UPDATE                | remote_table    |       |       |            |          | rmt    |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | remote_table    |     1 |   195 | 24990   (2)| 00:05:00 | rmt    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter(TO_NUMBER("A1"."ID")=123478)
 
Note
-----
   - fully remote statement
```

2. Also when i use count(*) for that remote_table it costs same as 24990.

**Note:** I use `INDEX` hint on select statement as below but it wont work

`SELECT /*+INDEX (a Column_index_name)*/ COUNT(*) FROM remote_table a WHERE a.ID = 123478;`

Below is the explain plan for select count(*) statement.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Inst   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT REMOTE|                 |     1 |     9 | 24990   (2)| 00:05:00 |        |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |                 |     1 |     9 |            |          |        |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | remote_table    |     1 |     9 | 24990   (2)| 00:05:00 | rmt    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter(TO_NUMBER("A1"."ID")=123478)
 
Note
-----
   - fully remote statement
```

Can anyone give suggestion on how to deal with this?

Comment: The DB links are the worst choice, they break the oracle execution plan giving you a full table scan.

Comment: What are the data types of `id` and `new_key`?  Is `id` a string (which would explain why there is a `to_number` in the predicate)?

Comment: Well, I do not see any other possibility than that the `ID` column is `VARCHAR2` @JustinCave. A number data type will not lead to the implicit conversion and `DATE` or other more *exotic* data types such as `CLOB` will raise `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: ...`

Comment: Not related to your issue but updating a remote table in a trigger is generally a bad idea.  That's a synchronous update so you're slowing down local transactions by involving things like two-phase commits and extra network traffic.  But more importantly, you're dramatically impacting availability since the local system now depends on the remote system being up and reachable.  There are a number of technologies that were built specifically to deal with replication that would almost certainly be preferrable to rolling your own solution.

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks for your advice and solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take some care on the column formats. Your column `ID`is `VARCAHR2` so you should query it as such.

Your predicate `ID = 123478` makes an +implicit conversion* that **prohibits index access**

Use `ID = '123478'` which will **enable index access**.

Examples with simulated table with `id varchar2(10)`

```
 SELECT * FROM tab a WHERE a.ID = 23478;
```

leads to xecution plan (cut for brevity)

```
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB  |  1081 |  2120K| 27171   (1)| 00:00:02 |

   1 - filter(TO_NUMBER("A"."ID")=23478)
```

But the query using the proper format literal

```
 SELECT * FROM tab a WHERE a.ID = '23478';
```

has the *right* plan

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |         |     1 |  2009 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TAB     |     1 |  2009 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TAB_IDX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("A"."ID"='23478')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. I drastically reduced cost from 24990 to 3..!